# How to Detect Dynamic frame in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I am trying to detect frame with dynamic target in selenium webdriver.
In selenium IDE i am getting details of frame like command "`selectframe`", `Target="CitrixMainFrameWI_hghjghjhj355"`, In the target dropdown no other value is present ,
I tried to detect this frame using command

`driver.switchto().frame("CitrixMainFrameWI_hghjghjhj355")`. But this target value is dynamically generated so i got error .
Can you please suggest me any solution for this

Comment: If you click in the dropdown in the IDE, you can get more values, like XPath and so on. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `frame(index)` or by naming the frames and only searching for CitrixMainFrame
(`contains("CitrixMainFrame"`).

More Details in this link:
http://joychester.blogspot.com/2010/09/switch-frame-and-windows-sample-code.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

// First find the frame.

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id^= 'CitrixMainFrameWI_']"));

// id^ means the id starts with the given value.

// You din't specify the tags, so i assumed as div tag. change it according to your code.

driver.switchto().frame(element);

Answer (score 0):

```
    String expectedFrameID="abc";
    List<WebElement> lst=d.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    System.out.println(lst.size());
    int flag=0;
    for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){
        String actualFrameID=lst.get(i).getAttribute("id");
        System.out.println(lst.get(i).getAttribute("id"));
        if(expectedFrameID.equals(actualFrameID)){
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
if(flag==1){//perform operation on frame}
```