# retrieve dynamic frame names w/ Selenium WebDriver and Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to run thousands of searches on a certain database and I'm using Python and Selenium  WebDriver to automate it. The thing is, the frame that contains the search results has a name that is dynamically generated. That name always begins the same way (say, "results_frame") and then it's followed by a bunch of numbers that change every time (like "results_frame1298120910290"). So, based on a few hours of googling, I tried using xpath:

```
framename = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//frame[contains(@name, 'results_frame')]")
driver.switch_to_frame(framename)
```

No good. When I print 'framename', what I get is this:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x101206350>,    <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x101206390>]
```

Instead of the actual name of the frame.

I've also tried using indexes (as in `driver.switch_to_frame(0)`, `driver.switch_to_frame(1)`, etc), as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376768/how-to-detect-dynamic-frame-in-selenium-webdriver), but no good either.

So, how can I retrieve a frame's name when that name is dynamically generated? Any thoughts?

(Python 2.7.5, Selenium 2.2.0, Mac OS X 10.6.8, Firefox 22.0)

Comment: I hope Richard have answered you so quick. Whenever doing xpath practice using .// instead of //

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find_elements_by_xpath` returns an object of type `WebElement`.  You need to use `get_attribute` to retrieve the value of an attribute from the `WebElement`.

```
framename = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frame[contains(@name, 'results_frame')]").get_attribute("name")
```

That should return the name you're looking for.