# python selenium function not defined?

Tags: python, selenium

please can anyone help me with this. It says my function is not defined.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.speedyshare.com/")

frame_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/frameset/frame").get_attribute("name")

driver.switch_to.frame(frame_name)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("selectfilebox")
elem.click()
```

I get this traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ro/selem.py", line 6, in <module>
    frame_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/frameset/frame").get_attribute("name")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
>>>
```

EDIT:

When I run

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.speedyshare.com/")

driver.switch_to.frame(0)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("selectfilebox")
elem.click()
```

AND

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.speedyshare.com/")

frame_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/frameset/frame").get_attribute("name")

driver.switch_to.frame(frame_name)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("selectfilebox")
elem.click()
```

They both keep running with no tracebacks but the mouse stays in the address bar.

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list. List objects do not have a `get_attribute` method.

Comment: Did you mean `find_element_by_xpath` (note singular)?

Comment: no, I've tried that also but I don't get a traceback and the mouse just stays in the address bar.

Answer (score 2):

While @Kevin and @jonrsharpe points are perfectly correct, you don't even need this line:

```
frame_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/frameset/frame").get_attribute("name")
```

You can simply pass the frame name to switch to:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("frame_name")
```

Or, the frame index (looks like it's just the first iframe on the page):

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
```

And selenium webdriver will take care of locating the frame and switching to it.

Comment: Thankyou but the frame is dynamic, I got that line from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954652/retrieve-dynamic-frame-names-w-selenium-webdriver-and-python

Comment: @booberz okay, you can then switch to it by index (see the update). Thanks.

Comment: @booberz also fixed the linked answer, thanks for pointing that.